# Return List<String> from Observable<List<String>>

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I download list of items from DB, it returns `Observable<List<String>>`:

```
Observable.just(getColorListRx()).take(2).subscribe(colorsList -> mSimpleStringAdapter.setList( ... ));
```

Then I want to make some operation (i.e., .take(2)) and set this sorted list via adapter on the screen in RecyclerView.

How can I do this? Can I convert somehow this `Observable<List<String>>` to List?

Comment: What is the return type of `getColorLitsRx`? Please show us its signature.

Comment: it returns Observable<List<String>>

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `take(2)`?

Comment: operator take(int n) emits only the first n items emitted by an Observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: By reading the comments of the question I realised my answer was missing some information. If `getColorListRx()` returns `Observable<List<String>>` you don't need to create another `Observable` by using `Observable.just()`. This will create a `Observable<Observable<List<String>>>` which is something you probably don't want. You can directly operate with `getColorListRx()` like this:

```
getColorListRx().take(2).subscribe(colorsList -> mSimpleStringAdapter.setList( ... ))
```

Second EDIT: If you need to grab the first two items from the list (`take(2)`) you can always perform a flatMap operation to transform the result of `Observable<List<String>>` into `Observable<String>`, take the first two items, and transform it back into a `Observable<List<String>>` like this:

```
getColorsListRx().flatMap(list -> Observable.from(list)).take(2).toList().subscribe(colorsList -> mSimpleStringAdapter.setList( ... )) .
```

Comment: @miensol But operator take() doesn't work. This pieace of code returns the same list as I put. It doesn't take 2 items as I wanted.

Comment: I think what you actually want is to grab two items from the list itself and not the observable. You can always perform a flatMap operation to transform the result of Observable<List<String>> into Observable<String>, take the first two items, and transform it back into a Observable<List<String>: `getColorsListRx().flatMap(list -> Observable.from(list)).take(2).toList().subscribe(colorsList -> mSimpleStringAdapter.setList( ... ))` . I can edit the answer to include this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[`Observable.just`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html) creates an observable that emits given item(s). This means `Observable.just(getColorListRx())` returns `Observable<Observable<List<String>>>`. Since `getColorListRx` already returns an observable you don't need to wrap it with `just`:

```
getColorListRx().take(2).subscribe(colorsList -> mSimpleStringAdapter.setList( ... ));
```